# Как четыре раскладки настроить в xkb?

Tags: linux, desktop, клавиатура

Раскладки, к примеру, english, русская, [image]
<sub>(источник: [omniglot.com](http://www.omniglot.com/images/langnames/nm_tengwar.gif))</sub>   и [image][image].

Хочу чтобы при выключенном Caps Lock происходило переключение по Alt-Shift между первыми двумя, а при включенном - между вторыми двумя. Возможно, настроить переключение надо не так, а как-то по-другому (например, чтобы отключение Caps переключало на последнюю использованную раскладку пары, а не на ту, которая получилась бы при учете состояния Alt-Shift).

Читал статьи Ивана Паскаля:

- http://pascal.tsu.ru/other/xkb/internals.html
- https://www.linux.org.ru/books/xkb/setup.html

но настроить не смог.

Answer (score 1):

в `xkb` есть только четыре «символа» для адресования раскладок (`group`):

`ISO_First_Group` — первая раскладка;

`ISO_Last_Group` — вторая раскладка;

`ISO_Next_Group` и `ISO_Prev_Group` — следующая и предыдущая раскладки.

для обращения к третьей и четвёртой раскладке можно использовать `action= LockGroup(group=3)` и `action=LockGroup(group=4)`.

эти `action`-ы можно закрепить либо за собственными новыми «символами», либо (что проще) переопределить поведение каких-нибудь двух неиспользуемых.

в качестве примера могу привести используемое мною решение, изложенное [в этом комментарии](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=49203&st=30&p=964761&#entry964761), конечно с поправкой на то, что я предпочитаю (и рекомендую) нециклическое переключение раскладок.

Comment: ответ непонятен. Что такое action? Ответ не соответствует политике stackoverflow - отвечать на вопрос в ответе, а не в ссылках. Зачем action-ы закреплять? Мне не важно, будет переключение циклическое или нет, ведь я не могу настроить даже хоть как-нибудь.

Comment: *Зачем action-ы закреплять?* — чтобы можно было их вызвать.